# Error in using "dumpdecrypted" to decrypt ios application

Tags: ios, header-files, jailbreak

I am trying to use '[dumpdecrypted](https://github.com/stefanesser/dumpdecrypted)' to decrypt iOS Application.
In accordance with README, I compiled dumpdecrypted.dylib and send it to my device, and I run command like below:

```
IPad-mini:/var/mobile root# DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=dumpdecrypted.dylib /var/mobile/Applications/XXXXX
XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/AppName.app/AppName
```

But there was an error:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library 'dumpdecrypted.dylib' because no suitable image found. Did find:
        dumpdecrypted.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1

Trace/BPT trap:5
```

How can I solve this problem??

My device is iPad mini 2(iOS7.1.2 Jailbreaked).

Comment: Closing this question claiming that it's about **general computing hardware and software** is flat-out absurd.  `dumpdecrypted` is not a general computing tool by any stretch of the imagination.  It's a reverse engineering programming tool.  It's entirely possible that the OP is using this to illegitimately steal technology, but it's also entirely possible that they're a security researcher, or trying to attack their own app.  People should either stop closing questions based on their suspicions and prejudices, or Stack Overflow should change the close criteria.

Comment: The mods might think that because it doesn't seem like the answer would have code in it, but even then, that still doesn't matter, and I agree that this should be left open.

Comment: You may need to move (or copy) the `dumpdecrypted.dylib` to the proper directory before it will work: https://github.com/iMokhles/DumpDecrypted7/issues/2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put `dumpdecrypted.dylib` in `/usr/lib`, then move to that directory (i.e., `cd /usr/lib`).

Then execute the command:

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=dumpdecrypted.dylib /var/mobile/Applications/D9DC2DBC-3C80-43E8-AF79-C01480A46271/rcplus.app/rcplus
```

You will find the output in the current directory (`/usr/lib`).

Comment: just a comment that the command does not need to include `mach-o decryption dumper`. That's part of the **output**.

Comment: @Nate I deleted `mach-o decryption dumper` from the end of "DYLD_INSERT...." line.